# Inserir dados vindo de um while que monta o form no banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array

como pegar os valor dos inputs que vem por array porque é o formulário é alimentado pelo cliente segue o código do formulário, dai ele quantas perguntas ele quiser no meu sistema de enquete, e cria as respostas.. queria saber como pegar o valor dos campos das perguntas que ele respondeu .. e cadastrar numa tabela.

```
$consulta2 = (" SELECT * 
FROM perguntas
WHERE id_feedback =  '$id'
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30 ");
$resultado = mysql_query($consulta2) or die("Erro no SQL: ".mysql_error());

while($lista = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){



    $id = anti_injection($lista['id']);
    $validacao_campo = anti_injection($lista['$validacao_campo']);
    $pergunta_principal = anti_injection($lista['$pergunta_principal']);
    $primeira_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$primeira_opcao']);
    $segunda_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$segunda_opcao']);
    $terceira_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$terceira_opcao']);
    $quarta_opcao = anti_injection($lista['$quarta_opcao']);

    ?>

    <fieldset>


        <br>
        <h2 class="fs-title"> <?php echo $lista['pergunta_principal']; ?> </h2>
         <input type="text" name="pergunta_principal" value="<?php echo $lista['pergunta_principal']; ?>" >
        <br>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

        <?php

if (!empty($lista['primeira_opcao'])){
echo $lista['primeira_opcao'] . "<input type='radio' value='" . $lista['primeira_opcao'] . "'   name='" . $lista['validacao_campo'] . "' > ";
}
if (!empty($lista['segunda_opcao'])){
echo $lista['segunda_opcao'] . "<input type='radio' value='" . $lista['segunda_opcao'] . "' name='" . $lista['validacao_campo'] . "' > ";
}
if (!empty($lista['terceira_opcao'])){
echo $lista['terceira_opcao'] . "<input type='radio' value='" . $lista['terceira_opcao'] . "'  name='" . $lista['validacao_campo'] . "'> ";
 }
if (!empty($lista['quarta_opcao'])){
echo $lista['quarta_opcao'] . "<input type='radio' value='" . $lista['quarta_opcao'] . "' name='" . $lista['validacao_campo'] . "' > ";
}

?>

        <br><br>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Anterior" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Proxima" />

    </fieldset>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: O que vem de onde? A primeira linha da pergunta está muito confusa.

Comment: <br>
        <h2 class="fs-title"> <?php echo $lista['pergunta_principal']; ?> </h2>
         <input type="text" name="pergunta_principal" value="<?php echo $lista['pergunta_principal']; ?>" >
        <br>

Comment: é ai que passo ela. esse pedaço do código fica repetindo, se o usuário cadastra outra pergunta com opçoes ele se repete .. queria saber como pego cada pergunta e a resposta selecionada. e envio por email ou cadastro no banco de dados